# "The attribute 'connectionStringName' is missing or empty." in Web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, parse-error

I'm all of a sudden getting the following error with my `Web.config` file and I don't understand what it means:

> Parser Error Message: The attribute 'connectionStringName' is missing or empty.

```
Line 24:       <providers>
Line 25:         <clear />
Line 26:        <add name="SMDPortalMembershipProvider" type="SMDPortalMembershipProvider" />
Line 27:       </providers>
Line 28:     </membership>
```

> Source File: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\web.config    Line: 26
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272

**Here's my config file:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
      connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="UODOTNET, Version=2.2.5.7444,
          Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=335F3FBD4BE82339"/>
        <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0,
          Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Default.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <membership defaultProvider="SMDPortalMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="SMDPortalMembershipProvider" type="SMDPortalMembershipProvider" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <sessionState cookieName="smd_portal_session" timeout="100"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

There is no error when I load the Default.aspx page, but as soon as my code calls upon the `Membership` class I'm getting the error.

Comment: Does your provider derive from a base class? Then perhaps it's the base class that's looking for the `connectionStringName` attribute?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your membership provider's config section needs a `connectionStringName` attribute. Without that `connectionStringName`, it doesn't know what database to look for membership information in.

You need to add the name of one of your the connection strings in the `connectionStrings` section to the `add` tag on line 26.

The `connectionStringName` attribute is **required** in order for your Web.Config to be valid. You can't use the `Membership` class without it.

Comment: The thing is that I have not yet inserted an connection string, I connect within my Provider.  I have tried removing `<connectionStrings>`.  Is this required for it to work?  My provider inherits `SqlMembershipProvider` but I'm just overriding the functions and putting my own code in there.

Comment: The bottom line is, ASP.NET recognizes you are using a membership provider, and it is looking for the connection string for the database that houses the membership information. This connection string is REQUIRED in order for your Web.Config to be valid.